# Regular expression to match only 1,2,3,6 numbers in third position

Tags: c#, regex

I am using below regular expression

```
((?i)[A-Za-z]{2}((\-\d((\-([^\S\r\n]{1,2}[A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z]{1,2}[^\S\r\n])|[^\S\r\n]{1,2})\-|\-([^\S\r\n]{1,2}\-?|[A-Za-z]{1,2}\-))|[^\S\r\n]\d[^\S\r\n][A-Za-z]{2}[^\S\r\n]|[^\S\r\n]\d([^\S\r\n]{2}[A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][^\S\r\n]{2})|[^\S\r\n]\d[A-Za-z]{1,2}[^\S\r\n]|\d([^\S\r\n][A-Za-z]{1,2}[^\S\r\n]|[A-Za-z]{1,2}[^\S\r\n]|[^\S\r\n]{1,2}|\/|[A-Za-z]{1,2}|\-))\d{6}|\/(\d((\/([A-Za-z]{1,2}[^\S\r\n]|[^\S\r\n][A-Za-z]|[^\S\r\n]{1,2})|[^\S\r\n]{1,2})\/|(\/([A-Za-z]{1,2}\/|[^\S\r\n]{1,2})|\/))\d{6}|\d{7})|[^\S\r\n](\d[^\S\r\n]{2}\d{6}|\d{7})|\-(\d\-\d{6}|\d{7})|[^\S\r\n]\d[A-Za-z]{1,2}\d{6}|\d[^\S\r\n][A-Za-z]{1,2}\d{6}|\d{7}))(?(?=[\d])$)
```

The format accepted is AA/B/CC/DDDDDD or AA-B-CC-DDDDDD, or AA B CC DDDDDD.
AA- 2 alphabet, B- one digit (accept only 1,2,3,6), CC- 2 alphabet (space also accepted)
in the case of AA B CC DDDDDD  if CC is ' c' or 'c ' then only one space should be there (AA B C DDDDDD, AA B CDDDDDD, AA BDDDDDD, AA B DDDDDD )

possible combinations are below:

- AA1BB123456
- AA1B123456
- AA1123456
- AA1  123456
- AA/1/BB/123456
- AA/1/  /123456
- AA/1/  123456
- AA/1  /123456
- AA/1/ /123456
- AA/1/123456
- AA/1/ 123456
- AA/1 /123456
- AA1/123456
- AA/1123456
- AA/1/B /123456
- AA/1/ B/123456
- AA/1/B/123456
- AA-1-BB-123456
- AA-1-  -123456
- AA-1-  123456
- AA-1  -123456
- AA-1- -123456
- AA-1-123456
- AA-1- 123456
- AA-1 -123456
- AA1-123456
- AA-1123456
- AA-1-B -123456
- AA-1- B-123456
- AA-1-B-123456
- AA 1 BB 123456
- AA 1  123456
- AA 1B 123456
- AA 1 BB 123456
- AA 1BB123456
- AA 1B  123456
- AA 1  B123456
- AA1 123456
- AA1  123456
- AA1 BB123456
- AA1BB 123456
- AA1 B 123456
- AA1 BB 123456
- AA1 B123456
- AA1B 123456
- AA1 B123456
- AA1 B 123456
- AA1  123456
- AA 1123456
- AA 1  123456

How can I change this regex to accept only numbers 1,2,3,6 in position B ?

if I use the below

```
((?i)[A-Za-z]{2}((\-[1,2,3,6]{1}((\-([^\S\r\n]{1,2}[A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z]{1,2}[^\S\r\n])|[^\S\r\n]{1,2})\-|\-([^\S\r\n]{1,2}\-?|[A-Za-z]{1,2}\-))|[^\S\r\n][1,2,3,6]{1}[^\S\r\n][A-Za-z]{2}[^\S\r\n]|[^\S\r\n][1,2,3,6]{1}([^\S\r\n]{2}[A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][^\S\r\n]{2})|[^\S\r\n][1,2,3,6]{1}[A-Za-z]{1,2}[^\S\r\n]|[1,2,3,6]{1}([^\S\r\n][A-Za-z]{1,2}[^\S\r\n]|[A-Za-z]{1,2}[^\S\r\n]|[^\S\r\n]{1,2}|\/|[A-Za-z]{1,2}|\-))\d{6}|\/([1,2,3,6]{1}((\/([A-Za-z]{1,2}[^\S\r\n]|[^\S\r\n][A-Za-z]|[^\S\r\n]{1,2})|[^\S\r\n]{1,2})\/|(\/([A-Za-z]{1,2}\/|[^\S\r\n]{1,2})|\/))\d{6}|\d{7})|[^\S\r\n](\d[^\S\r\n]{2}\d{6}|\d{7})|\-([1,2,3,6]{1}\-\d{6}|\d{7})|[^\S\r\n]\d[A-Za-z]{1,2}\d{6}|[1,2,3,6]{1}[^\S\r\n][A-Za-z]{1,2}\d{6}|\d{7}))(?(?=[\d])$)
```

now it accepts below

- AA4123456,
- AA-4123456
- AA 4  123456
- AA 4BB123456
- AA 4123456
- AA 4  123456

but here B is 4 which should not be accepted.

any help ?

Comment: How do you plan to maintain such a massive regex? Have you considered just parsing the string with C# (`string.Split()` etc.)?

Comment: Ignoring the fact that I'm too lazy to read and understand that regex (imagine how your co-workers will feel when they have to find/fix a bug in there), I'm also having trouble understanding the format of your inputs. I can't even tell where the example inputs begin and end due to the poor formatting of the question.

Comment: That's a heavily convoluted regex and a pain to read. Also if you use *case insensitive* flag `(?i)` you don't need to write `[A-Za-z]`. I'd start over with [some more simple regex](https://regex101.com/r/xb2Ptr/1).

Answer (score 4):

Your `[1,2,3,6]` character class is not just matching one of the digits `1`, `2`, `3`, `6` but also a comma. Because you included comma(s) in that character class. Use the character class `[1236]` instead, as it will match only one of `1`, `2`, `3`, `6` but no comma.

Then, `[^\S\r\n]` matches anything that is not a white-space, `\r` or `\n` character. Which means, it would match `1`, `2`, `3`, `6` among other things, and it would also match `4`. This could be a candidate for matching the unwanted `4` character. Then there are also `\d`, `\d{6}` and `\d{7}` in your pattern, which are also possible candidates for matching a sequence of digits beginning with a `4`, as some of those seem to appear at the beginning of what looks to my hurting eyes like too-clever-for-their-own-good attempts at defining alternations of sub-patterns.

I don't know whether there are other issues in your regex pattern. I find such complex regex pattern with a lot of nested groups and alternations on different nesting levels quite unreadable and unmaintainable and which i really wouldn't like to touch even with a ten-foot pole. And considering you appearing to be on shaky grounds regarding the basics of .NET regex syntax -- as exemplified by your incorrect `[1,2,3,6]` character class -- my honest answer would rather tend towards suggesting to stay away from these huge incomprehensible regex patterns. Instead i'd like to suggest for each of the text patterns/combinations you need to match you would create individual, separate regex patterns that are smaller, simpler, and easier to read, maintain, test and validate.

If for some reason (and the reason is always the universe being an unfunny jerk) you *must* use a single regex pattern, take advantage of the `(?x)` option. [`(?x)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options#ignore-white-space) causes white-spaces (including line breaks) in the regex pattern itself to be ignored. This allows you to "format" your regex in a more readable way. For example, lets say you need to match these text combinations case-insensitively:

- aaabbbccc
- aaaxy
- 122223

(These are of course only rather simple stand-ins for your actual text combinations that you described as `AA/B/CC/DDDDDD`, `AA-B-CC-DDDDDD`, or `AA B CC DDDDDD`.)

You could then write your single regex pattern like this (including white-spaces and line breaks):

```
(?xi)
  \b a{3}b{3}c{3} \b
  | \b a{3}xy \b
  | \b 12{4}3 \b
```

([Regex Storm online example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fxi%29%0d%0a++%5cb+a%7b3%7db%7b3%7dc%7b3%7d+%5cb%0d%0a++%7c+%5cb+a%7b3%7dxy+%5cb%0d%0a++%7c+%5cb+12%7b4%7d3+%5cb&i=aaabbbccc+aabbccc+axy+aaaxy+122223+123+AAAXY%0d%0a))

Note that each line in the pattern represents a pattern of one of the text combinations to be matched (except the first line and the alternation symbol `|`, of course). To a degree, it's readable. To a degree, it's maintainable. The patterns for the different text combinations can be relatively easily isolated or copy'n'pasted into an online regex tester for easy testing and validation.

Resist the urge to "optimize" and do not mash regex patterns for different text combinations together. Generally, with respect to regex patterns it's a good idea to trade redundancy for better readability and maintainability the more complex a pattern becomes. It's not a hard science of course, with what is/feels readable being subjective to a degree. That said, while it is technically possible to shorten my example regex pattern to something like this:

```
(?xi) \b (
  ( a{3} ( b{3}c{3} | xy ) )
  | 12{4}3
) \b
```

i would not recommend to do this. It's much less readable both in terms of what the regex pattern technically does and what the intent behind the pattern is. You cannot easily test a pattern for an individual text combination because you can't simply isolate and copy'n'paste it into a regex tester without additional editing. So it becomes harder to correctly understand and maintain/troubleshoot. Extend this to larger regex patterns, and these kind of "optimizations" quickly turn into hard-to-solve puzzles like that in your question... ;-)

Comment: From your answer one could get the misconception that `[1236]` and `[1..6]` are the same. I would rephrase to make sure it couldn't be understood like that.

Comment: @PalleDue, you're absolutely right. Edit incoming... Thanks!